# Pretty print JSON to a file using Groovy without unicode escaping

Tags: json, groovy, unicode

I have been all over google and SO trying to figure out how I can pretty print JSON to a file using groovy without unicode characters getting escaped.

```
String json = JsonOutput.toJson([name: 'Johan Söder', age: 42])
String prettyJson = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json)
File newFile = new File("data.json")
newFile.write(prettyJson)
```

Which results in the file content looking like:

```
{
    "name": "Johan S\u00f6der",
    "age": 42
}
```

Using JsonGenerator and the option disableUnicodeEscaping works, but JsonGenerator does not have a pretty print option so it looks like this:

```
{"name":"Johan Söder","age":42}
```

Which is fine for this small example, but my real output isn't this small and needs to be pretty printed.

Passing the result of JsonGenerator to JsonOutput.prettyPrint reintroduces the unicode escaped characters. Passing the pretty print from JsonOutput to the JsonGenerator creates a whole mess:

```
"{\n    \"name\": \"Johan S\\u00f6der\",\n    \"age\": 42\n}"
```

With unicode escped characters and not even pretty printed.

I have also tried using JsonBuilder with a JsonGenerator:

```
JsonGenerator generator = new JsonGenerator.Options().disableUnicodeEscaping().build()
String prettyString = new JsonBuilder([name: 'Johan Söder', age: 42], generator).toPrettyString()
File newFile = new File("data.json")
newFile.write(prettyString)
```

But the result is still the same:

```
{
    "name": "Johan S\u00f6der",
    "age": 42
}
```

So now I post this question in the hopes that someone has the solution to be able to pretty print to a file without unicode escaped characters. I would like a Groovy solution without additional libraries.

Comment: As a quick note, escaped unicode characters are the same as the original, they are just escaped...  When you read the file back into Groovy, you get back to `Johan Söder`

Comment: Yeah, I am doing that as well, but the file needs to be decently human readable in between. Mainly for support and investigation purposes if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJavaScript` seems to do the trick:

```
import groovy.json.*

String json = JsonOutput.toJson([name: 'Johan Söder', age: 42])
String prettyJson = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJavaScript(
    JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json)
)
File newFile = new File("data.json")
newFile.write(prettyJson)
```

Edit: as rightfully pointed out by @daggett, this will unescape special characters like `"`, making the json file invalid if present. I was first surprised that there is no built-in method to handle this. Even [`apache commons unescapeJson`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJson(java.lang.String)) seems to do the same as `unescapeJavaScript`.

One way I have found is to use Google [gson](https://github.com/google/gson):

```
@Grab('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1')
import com.google.gson.*

String prettyString = new GsonBuilder()
    .setPrettyPrinting()
    .create()
    .toJson([name: 'Johan " Söder', age: 42])

File newFile = new File("data.json")
newFile.write(prettyString)
```

Comment: Seems to fill the need I have currently. But I am guessing that this "unescapes" much more than just Unicode characters?

Comment: Looks like Unicode and standard escaped characters https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-json/src/main/java/groovy/json/StringEscapeUtils.java#L304

Comment: note. for `'Johan " Söder'` this code  produces incorrect json : `{ "name": "Johan " Söder" }`

Comment: @daggett sure, but 'Johan " Söder' doesn't really make sense as data though? In real data, when would you have miss-matched quotations? Then you probably have other issue in your code.

Comment: to have doublequote in data is a valid case - for example in US quite often nickname quoted between first/last names like this: `Joshua "Josh" LastName`.

Comment: @daggett's remark is perfectly valid and their answer provide a fix for the problem (+1). I updated my answer as well with a solution using gson.

Answer (score 2):

I'm suggesting to unescape only unicode characters

```
import groovy.json.*

String json = JsonOutput.toJson([name: 'Johan " Söder', age: 42]) // added doublequote for test
String prettyJson = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json)
prettyJson = prettyJson.replaceAll(/\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/){Integer.parseInt(it[1], 16) as char}
File newFile = new File("data.json")
newFile.write(prettyJson)
```

result:

```
{
    "name": "Johan \" Söder",
    "age": 42
}
```